# Eclipse import from git not recognizing source folders

Tags: java, git, eclipse

I wanted to share a Java project with another computer. I went on the first computer and created a GitHub repo out of it by clicking `Team -> Share Project -> Create -> Finish`. Then, I went to the other computer and clicked `Import -> Projects from Git -> pasted in the GitHub link -> next, next, next`. But when I opened the project, all the packages were like `src.foo` and `src.bar`. It didn't recognize the "src" folder was a source folder. Did I do one of these steps wrong?

Comment: There are several questions I would ask. Before you imported the project to Eclipse, was a .project and .classpath file already in the directory (because they were stored in git)? If so, their contents might be useful. When you imported it, did it have "Maven" in the "Import As" column?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is:

1. Create an empty folder in your workspace;
2. In the Terminal, execute the command git clone ;
3. In the Terminal, move to your project folder: cd folder-name;
4. Open Eclipse;
5. Import the project;